# How to delete a object from database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to delete a object from my database using ASP.NET MVC. I have connected to the database with Entity Framework. I have made this code for my controller named `Delete`.

```
// DELETE-POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    var obj = _db.Project.Find(id);

    if(obj == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    _db.Project.Remove(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Then I created a button with a link to my controller

```
<a asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg text-white w-30">Delete</a>
```

I had expect that my object should disappear. But I get an issue when I press the button. It only returns a blank site with a message that the site does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add Id to your ancor tag. Try to use this:

```
<a asp-controller="...Controller"   asp-action="Delete" 
       asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg text-white w-30">
Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass id from view.

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg text-white w-30">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you so much !